# Simple way to have button open blank screen

Tags: android, button

So if anyone has seen my previous post, the first button (which I was able to properly code thanks to support here) brings you to a site via browser where you can sign up for an account -- the next button I have I want to be the sign in button where it will bring you to another screen -- I'd like to start off with a blank screen, what's the most simple way to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want, you are not very specific, I'm guessing you want to open another activity, or change the layout? Let say you want to change your layout. In this folder:

> res/layout

folder, you have XML layouts that the activity will display when you want it to. Lets say you have a class named Main that you can find here:

> src/com.your.package.name/Main.java

and the default layout file named main.xml you can find here:

> res/layout/main.xml

The main.xml is your main 'screen', so create a new XML layout file (Right Click> New> Other> Android XML file and in the 'File' input box enter the desired name.) This XML file will be your second screen. Edit it so you like it. Make sure you have a button in main.xml, and edit the ID so you know it. Open Main.java and add this code:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theButtonIdYouEntered); // theButtonIdYouEntered is the ID you set the button too in the XML file
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.theSecondLayoutXmlFile); // theSecondLayoutXmlFile is what you named the second XML layout file, your second 'screen'
            }
        });
```

Now when you click on your button, it should change 'screen', if you want to know for how to change activity, just say. Hope this helps, zeokila

Comment: `final Button signButton = (Button)      findViewById(R.id.signButton); 
                signButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.main2); 
                    }
                });`

Upon clicking my second button nothing appears to happen -- although there are no errors in my code! Let me know if you need anymore info for troubleshooting -- I really appreciate the help :)